# Getting Null Adapter Error : E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Trying to retrieve data and place it into RecyclerView. But i always end up getting a null adapter error. My List Adapter is not being recognized.

I have initialized adapter and recyclerview in OnCreate(), OnViewCreated() nothing changed except app-crash.

Can you guys shed any light please?

My List Adapter:

```
public class PostListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostListAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private static final String TAG = "PostListAdapter";
    private static final int NUM_GRID_COLUMNS = 3;

    private ArrayList<Post> mPosts;
    private Context mContext;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        SquareImageView mPostImage;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mPostImage = (SquareImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);

            int gridWidth = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            int imageWidth = gridWidth/NUM_GRID_COLUMNS;
            mPostImage.setMaxHeight(imageWidth);
            mPostImage.setMaxWidth(imageWidth);
        }
    }

    ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(mContext);




    public PostListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Post> posts) {
        mPosts = posts;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_view_post, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mContext));

        UniversalImageLoader.setImage(mPosts.get(position).getImage(), holder.mPostImage);
        //GlideApp.with(mContext).load(mPosts.get(position)).into(holder.mPostImage);

        //imageLoader.displayImage(mPosts.get(position).getImage(), holder.mPostImage);

        final int pos = position;
        holder.mPostImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: selected a post");
                //TODO

                //view the post in more detail

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPosts.size();
    }


}
```

My Fragment (where i initiliaze adapter and recyclerview):

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        mFilters = view.findViewById(R.id.ic_search);
        mSearchText = view.findViewById(R.id.input_search);
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mFrameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.container);

        getElasticSearchPassword();
        init();

        return view;
    }

    private void setupPostsList(){
        RecyclerViewMargin itemDecorator = new RecyclerViewMargin(GRID_ITEM_MARGIN, NUM_GRID_COLUMNS);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecorator);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), NUM_GRID_COLUMNS);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new PostListAdapter(getActivity(), mPosts);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }


    private void init(){
        mFilters.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating to filters activity.");
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FiltersActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                        ||actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                        || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                    mPosts = new ArrayList<Post>();

                    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build();

                    ElasticSearchAPI searchAPI = retrofit.create(ElasticSearchAPI.class);

                    HashMap<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headerMap.put("Authorization", Credentials.basic("", mElasticSearchPassword));

                    String searchString = "";

                    if(!mSearchText.equals("")){
                        searchString = searchString + mSearchText.getText().toString() + "*";
                    }
                    if(!mPrefCity.equals("")){
                        searchString = searchString + " city:" + mPrefCity;
                    }
                    if(!mPrefStateProv.equals("")){
                        searchString = searchString + " state_province:" + mPrefStateProv;
                    }
                    if(!mPrefCountry.equals("")){
                        searchString = searchString + " country:" + mPrefCountry;
                    }

                    Call<HitsObject> call = searchAPI.search(headerMap, "AND", searchString);

                    call.enqueue(new Callback<HitsObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<HitsObject> call, Response<HitsObject> response) {

                            HitsList hitsList = new HitsList();
                            String jsonResponse = "";
                            try{
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: server response: " + response.toString());

                                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                                    hitsList = response.body().getHits();
                                }else{
                                    jsonResponse = response.errorBody().string();
                                }

                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: hits: " + hitsList);

                                for(int i = 0; i < hitsList.getPostIndex().size(); i++){
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: data: " + hitsList.getPostIndex().get(i).getPost().toString());
                                    mPosts.add(hitsList.getPostIndex().get(i).getPost());
                                }

                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: size: " + mPosts.size());
                                //setup the list of posts
                                setupPostsList();



                            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
                            }
                            catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: IndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage() );
                            }
                            catch (IOException e){
                                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<HitsObject> call, Throwable t) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage() );
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "search failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void viewPost(String postId){
        ViewPostFragment fragment = new ViewPostFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(getString(R.string.arg_post_id), postId);
        fragment.setArguments(args);


        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, getString(R.string.fragment_view_post));
        transaction.addToBackStack(getString(R.string.fragment_view_post));
        transaction.commit();

        mFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getFilters();
    }

    private void getElasticSearchPassword(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getElasticSearchPassword: retrieving elasticsearch password.");

        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child(getString(R.string.node_elasticsearch))
                .orderByValue();

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DataSnapshot singleSnapshot = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();
                mElasticSearchPassword = singleSnapshot.getValue().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }




    private void getFilters(){
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mPrefCity = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.preferences_city), "");
        mPrefStateProv = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.preferences_state_province), "");
        mPrefCountry = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.preferences_country), "");

        Log.d(TAG, "getFilters: got filters: \ncity: " + mPrefCity + "\nState/Prov: " + mPrefStateProv
                + "\nCountry: " + mPrefCountry);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you never call the method `setupPostsList()`. You should move your code in Fragment from `onCreateView()` to `onViewCreated()` - that's the mehod where all views in fragment are created and you can use findViewById(). First find all view by ids and then call method `setupPostsList()` to set up the recycle view.

Comment: Just tried your way but nothing changed. Thanks for your answer. Btw I do call the method setupPostsList() where the data gets loaded.

Comment: Now i've added  the whole code from the Fragment to my question.